# Does Visual Studio Code have an auto-import feature for Java??

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Does VS Code have an auto-import function or hot key for Java?

I installed Java Extension Pack but I found that I need to import every library manually.

Comment: Not fully automatic but https://github.com/tushortz/vscode-Java-Imports may be helpful although you still need to write some text to popup the suggestion

Answer (score 76):

For organize imports inside a java file

press **SHIFT+ ALT + O**

The vscode has also the option of enable auto organize imports on save action

[image]

Comment: For mac do option+shift+o

Comment: For me it doesn't appearing this option for java import, how can i do that?

Comment: He's asking about how to automize imports, not organizing already existing imports. This command will only tidy things up it won't actually import anything. At least at this point.

Answer (score 7):

Open the settings.json file (Ctrl+Shift+P than type settings.json) and add this:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
},
```

when you save it will works :D

Kudos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svCTgx6abFc

Answer (score 3):

It is **shift+option+o** for vscode macos

Answer (score -2):

A) in order to have everything working just like intellij or eclipse, there is an extension, install it, Ctrl+Shift+P ==> then write create java project.

B) now that you have the project scaffold right, just right click on the editor, choose source action, then organize imports and select the right libraries to be imported.

Comment: @soz this is it: Eclipse New Java Project