# Is there a VS-code extension for java autoimport?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there's an extension for vs-code that automatically imports java/kotlin libs?

It would solve the problem indicated by the red squiggle here.

[image]

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534584/java-auto-import-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Java Extension pack from Microsoft you can auto import with

> Shift + Alt + O

The Command name is Organize Imports.